# Making centroids for vector grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, model

I need to add polygon centroids to vector grid but I can't... 
I have output grid like polygon, but I can't choose layer to make centroids

I need it for R studio and pollution model of city.

QGIS 2,4,0

[image: QGIS Polygon centroids]

Comment: I am not sure what do you want but perhaps you need gCentroid from rgeos package in R. With this,if you have a polygon you can find the centroid of it.

Comment: ive made vector grid and i need to make centeroid in each cell 
but with vector > geometry tools > polygon centeroids i cant choose grid layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grid is not made of polygons. I suspect its lines. Check the "geometry type" section of the metadata section of the layer properties. I'll wager its not "Polygon"...

If you made it with the "Vector Grid" tool then you should have ticked "Output grid as polygons" instead of "Output grid as lines".